# Inverting `member` in Curry (PAKCS) gives no answers

Tags: functional-programming, logic-programming, curry, functional-logic-progr

With this definition:

```
member _ [] = False
member x (h:t) = if x == h then True else member x t
```

PAKCS 2.0.1 (from Ubuntu 18.04) gives no answers, warnings or errors:

```
    Top-level binding with no type signature:
      member :: Prelude.Eq a => a -> [a] -> Prelude.Bool
member> member x [1, 2, 3] =:= True where x free
member>
```

I expected to see 3 values. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The implementation of `member` with unifying `=:=` instead of the non-unifying `==` wouldn't be correct: to evaluate the `if then else` term, it would first evaluate `x =:= h` by searching for a solution. If it unifies `x` with `h` successfully, this term has a value (always `True`) and the evaluation proceeds to `if then else`. Otherwise, if there are no solutions, the whole expression (the whole function) has no solutions. The `else` part never would get evaluated and give a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program <smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?75> gives only one solution since the rule

```
member x (h:t) = if x =:= h then True else member x t
```

unifies `x` with the first element of the list and yields `True` and nothing else.
Note that `(=:=)` is a unification constraint rather than a Boolean test. This means that `x =:= 1` binds `x` to `1` (in order to satisfy the constraint) and yields `True` but *never* `False`. Hence, `2 =:= 1` simply fails rather than yielding `False`. On the other hand, `2 == 1` yields `False`. Thus, you might expect that `x == 1` binds `x` to `1` yielding `True` or binds `x` to `2`, `3`, `4`,... yielding `False`. Actually, this is the case in the Curry implementation [KiCS2](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/) but PAKCS is for some reason more restricted so that it suspends on this expression.

One further remark: one can view `(=:=)` as an optimization of `(==)` which can be used in case where only the result `True` is required, e.g., in conditions of rules. Therefore, newer PAKCS implementation automatically transform `(==)` into `(=:=)` in such cases so that only `(==)` might be used in source programs. Further details can be found in [this paper](http://doi.org/10.1007/s00165-016-0399-6).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in Curry programming language, `==` is not a kind of function that can unify non-determinate values.

Doing some experiments with another implementation of Curry that happened to be installed on my system (`curry-0.9.12-alt1.dev20141223.x86_64`):

```
Prelude> (x == 'a') =:= True where x free
Suspended
Prelude> let match_a 'a' = True in match_a x =:= True where x free
{x = 'a'}
Prelude>
```

Comment: If I replace `==` with `=:=` in `member` definition, then I get 1 answer (2 are still missing)

Comment: @MaxB Better show your code with `=:=`, because its return type is not `Bool`, so `==` and `=:=` are not interchangeable. This way it works for me: `Prelude> let memberConstr x (h:t) = (x =:= h) ? memberConstr x t in memberConstr x [1, 2, 3] where x free` gives:
`{x = 1}
More solutions? [Y(es)/n(o)/a(ll)] a
{x = 2}
{x = 3}
Prelude> 
`

Comment: Literally 1 char difference from the code in the Q. `:t member` gives me `member :: a -> [a] -> Bool`. When I type your string (from the comment above) I get all 3 answers *at once*. This might be a difference in versions/implementations. You are not using `pakcs`?

Comment: @MaxB No, I ran my tests in the different implementation (the one written in C, known under the name Muenster Curry), which is also quite old in my case. I'll try your 1 char difference and see, but my expectation is that the types won't match. Perhaps, Curry specs changed since then so that `=:=` has a different type in modern times.What does `:t (=:=)` show for you? Mine is: `Prelude> :t (=:=)
_1 -> _1 -> Success
` Perhaps, instead of `Success`, it's polymorphic in your PAKCS.

Comment: @MaxB Yes, in my case: `Term: x =:= h
Inferred type: Success
Expected type: Bool
Types Bool and Success are incompatible
`

Comment: @MaxB There might be a runtime PAKCS option to list all solutions... And by default you might be seeing only the first solution.

Comment: PAKCS has type classes. I think that's what's different. Output: `(=:=) :: a -> a -> Bool` and `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`

Comment: You can also use Curry online: http://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/ (Use the menu on top of the page)

Comment: @MaxB Yes, SmapIE has such an option: `PAKCS 2.2.0 /all-values`

Comment: For some reason (yet unclear to me), my program with `memberConstr` gives all 3 solutions <https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?76> in PAKCS 2.2.0 /all-solutions, but yours <https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?75> only one...